# Sychronous Json vs Asychonrous Json return

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, angular

Right now, I have two functions that are returning JSON data.

```
searchAjax(url: any): any
{
    let new_data: any;
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json", 
        async: false

    }).responseText;
}

search(): Promise<any> 
{
    return this.http.get('app/php/search.php')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            //console.log("search");
            console.log(response.json());
            response.json();
            })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now `searchAjax` correctly returns me the json data but is it synchronous, while `search` just returns me null, even though the `console.log(respon.json())` actually prints the correct json object.

I was just wondering if there was a way to get the JSON data asychronously or if getting the data synchronously is good enough.

Comment: You *never* want to use synchronous Ajax. Forget that this feature exists.

Comment: What Tomalak said. synchronous is generally considered to be a last resort - it locks up the browser so the user can't do anything else, any animations stop, they can't click on things. There's almost never a reason to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a promise handler is what you return in the end. Your code did not return anything.

```
search(): Promise<any> 
{
    return this.http.get('app/php/search.php')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        //  ^^^^^^
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

or, for short (here the `return` is implicit, but you must keep in mind that it is there):

```
search(): Promise<any> 
{
    return this.http.get('app/php/search.php')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: bleh of course. I had the bottom one before, but at some point it was still returning null (I had `json().data` probably). So what does the `json().data` return anyway? If you know. I saw it on angular as `json().data as Hero[]`

Comment: I have no idea what `json().data` is in your case. Set a breakpoint and find out.